# isDraggingOver when isDropDisabled react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

> The same question on Github - https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1712

**Question:**

Is it possible to handle `isDraggingOver` when `isDropDisabled` is true? I want to highlight the list with red border when it's closed.

**Codesandbox** - https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-bush-kz3b1

**Code:**
<sub>For example we have two lists</sub>

```
import cn from "classnames"

const Lists = () => {
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState([false, false]);
  return (
    <>
      <Droppable droppableId="droppable-1" isDropDisabled={isCollapsed[0]}>
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
          <section className={cn({
            "dragging-over": snapshot.isDraggingOver,
            "dragging-over-collapsed": snapshot.isDraggingOver && isCollapsed[0]
          })}>{/*...items...*/}</section>
        )}
      </Droppable>
      <Droppable droppableId="droppable-2" isDropDisabled={isCollapsed[1]}>
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
          <section className={cn({
            "dragging-over": snapshot.isDraggingOver,
            "dragging-over-collapsed": snapshot.isDraggingOver && isCollapsed[0]
          })}>{/*...items...*/}</section>
        )}
      </Droppable>
    </>
  );
}
```